# Is exists level 2 cache for Entity Framework 6+ not updating whole entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

All level 2 cache libraries i found clears entity (invalidate entity)  in cache when updating / deleting.Then when i call some view that use entity, it call DB for whole table. So, is there a cache for Entity Framework 6+ not deleting whole entity from cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Our Query Cache `http://entityframework-plus.net/query-cache` doesn't invalidate or update the whole entity.

Our feature simple cache the result into the Memory Cache and that's all!